# Cannot navigate from an already loaded webpage to another with vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have the following in order to get data from webpage and I arrange them per column in a worksheet. I take one of the data which is a URL and after I put them in cells I want to navigate again to that page and get my last info.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer: Set ie = New InternetExplorer
Dim i As Long
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 20

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate2 "https://www.skroutz.gr/s/8988836/Mattel-Hot-Wheels-%CE%91%CF%85%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%B7%CF%84%CE%AC%CE%BA%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CE%A3%CE%B5%CF%84-%CF%84%CF%89%CE%BD-10.html"

    While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim finalPrices As Object, sellers As Object, availability As Object
    Dim products As Object, t As Date
    Set products = .Document.querySelectorAll(".card.js-product-card")
    t = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
        ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);", "javascript"
        Set finalPrices = .Document.querySelectorAll(".card.js-product-card span.final-price")
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop Until finalPrices.Length = products.Length


    Set sellers = .Document.querySelectorAll(".card.js-product-card .shop.cf a[title]")
    Set availability = .Document.querySelectorAll(".card.js-product-card span.availability")
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTINGS")
        For i = 0 To 5

            If availability.Item(i).innerText = "Άμεσα Διαθέσιμο σε 1 έως 3 ημέρες" Then

            .Cells(2, i + 4) = sellers.Item(i)
            .Cells(3, i + 4) = finalPrices.Item(i).innerText
            .Cells(4, i + 4) = availability.Item(i).innerText
           End If        
        Next

        .Columns("D:I").AutoFit

    ie.Quit


    'Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    'DoEvents
    'Loop

    'Dim place As Object, mylink As String


    'For i = 0 To 5
    '        ie.Visible = True

    '        mylink = .Cells(2, i + 4).Value
    '        If mylink <> "" Then
    '        ie.Navigate2 mylink
    '        Set place = ie.Document.querySelector(".shop-stores.cf")
    '        .Cells(5, i + 4) = place.innerText
    '        End If

    'Next
    End With


 End With
End Sub
```

If I add the following which checks the cell with a URL, and if it has value inside then opens the URL gets the value and finish then I get Automation Error

```
Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Dim place As Object, mylink As String


For i = 0 To 5
        ie.Visible = True

        mylink = .Cells(2, i + 4).Value
        If mylink <> "" Then
        ie.Navigate2 mylink
        Set place = ie.Document.querySelector(".shop-stores.cf")
        .Cells(5, i + 4) = place.innerText
        End If

Next
```

Then I get an Automation error on the following line

```
Set place = ie.Document.querySelector(".shop-stores.cf")
```

Can't go from one page to another? 
Do I have to create a different sub and call it from GetInfo() sub?

Comment: Make sure you have another proper wait after the second navigate. And you don’t need to have ie.visible within the loop.

Comment: Can you provide an example second url please?

Comment: What other proper wait you mean? The second link is https://www.skroutz.gr/m/3851/Besttoys#shop-presentation

Comment: Did I put my extra code in right position ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a proper wait after each navigate2 and make your ie object visible outside of all loops e.g. structure. You could add in a timed loop for setting of `place` variable. I have added a safeguard test of `If Not Is Nothing`. Have your `.Quit` at the end after you have finished with the `ie` object.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, i As Long
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 20

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.skroutz.gr/s/8988836/Mattel-Hot-Wheels-%CE%91%CF%85%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%B7%CF%84%CE%AC%CE%BA%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CE%A3%CE%B5%CF%84-%CF%84%CF%89%CE%BD-10.html"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        'code with first link

        Dim place As Object, mylink As String

        For i = 0 To 5
            mylink = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i + 4).Value
            If mylink <> vbNullString Then
                .Navigate2 mylink
                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                On Error Resume Next
                Set place = .document.querySelector(".shop-stores.cf")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not place Is Nothing Then
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(5, i + 4) = place.innerText
                    Set place  = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get automation error on While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend,  now

Comment: sometimes happens when IE hasn't closed properly.  Close IE. Give a short wait and try to run code again.

Comment: There wasn't a .quit in mine. Though I just added at the end. If you have it during the loop you no longer have the ie object to work with so you will get an automation error. You want .quit at the end when you have finished using the ie object.